# Cabal failing to install network-2.6.3.1 on Linux

Tags: linux, haskell, ubuntu-14.04, cabal, hackage

In short I am fairly new to the Haskell world and am having an issue installing a package with a dependency on network-2.6.3.1.

```
cabal install happstack-server
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring network-2.6.3.1...
Failed to install network-2.6.3.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
happstack-server-7.4.6.2 depends on network-2.6.3.1 which failed to install.
hslogger-1.2.10 depends on network-2.6.3.1 which failed to install.
network-2.6.3.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 127
sendfile-0.7.9 depends on network-2.6.3.1 which failed to install.
```

Installing network on its own yields similar results. Are there any usual suspects or recommended steps for erroring installations? I have successfully installed other packages, ghcid, ghc-mod etc.

### Update

```
> ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
> cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2 using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library"
> ghc-pkg list 
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d
   Cabal-1.16.0
   GLURaw-1.3.0.0
   GLUT-2.4.0.0
   HTTP-4000.2.8
   HUnit-1.2.5.2
   MonadCatchIO-mtl-0.3.0.5
   OpenGL-2.8.0.0
   OpenGLRaw-1.3.0.0
   QuickCheck-2.6
   array-0.4.0.1
   async-2.0.1.4
   attoparsec-0.10.4.0
   base-4.6.0.1
   bin-package-db-0.0.0.0
   binary-0.5.1.1
   bytestring-0.10.0.2
   case-insensitive-1.1.0.2
   cgi-3001.1.8.3
   containers-0.5.0.0
   deepseq-1.3.0.1
   directory-1.2.0.1
   extensible-exceptions-0.1.1.4
   fgl-5.4.2.4
   filepath-1.3.0.1
   ghc-7.6.3
   ghc-prim-0.3.0.0
   hashable-1.2.1.0
   haskell-src-1.0.1.5
   haskell2010-1.1.1.0
   haskell98-2.0.0.2
   hoopl-3.9.0.0
   hpc-0.6.0.0
   html-1.0.1.2
   integer-gmp-0.5.0.0
   mtl-2.1.2
   network-2.4.1.2
   old-locale-1.0.0.5
   old-time-1.1.0.1
   parallel-3.2.0.3
   parsec-3.1.3
   pretty-1.1.1.0
   primitive-0.5.0.1
   process-1.1.0.2
   random-1.0.1.1
   regex-base-0.93.2
   regex-compat-0.95.1
   regex-posix-0.95.2
   rts-1.0
   split-0.2.2
   stm-2.4.2
   syb-0.4.0
   template-haskell-2.8.0.0
   text-0.11.3.1
   time-1.4.0.1
   transformers-0.3.0.0
   unix-2.6.0.1
   unordered-containers-0.2.3.0
   vector-0.10.0.1
   xhtml-3000.2.1
   zlib-0.5.4.1
/home/myHome/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d
   base64-bytestring-1.0.0.1
   blaze-builder-0.4.0.2
   blaze-html-0.8.1.2
   blaze-markup-0.7.1.0
   bytestring-0.10.8.1
   bytestring-builder-0.10.8.1.0
   cereal-0.5.3.0
   exceptions-0.8.3
   fail-4.9.0.0
   monad-control-1.0.1.0
   mtl-2.2.1
   network-uri-2.6.1.0
   parsec-3.1.11
   system-filepath-0.4.13.4
   threads-0.5.1.4
   time-compat-0.1.0.3
   transformers-0.5.2.0
   transformers-base-0.4.4
   transformers-compat-0.5.1.4
   utf8-string-1.0.1.1
```

Comment: Can you try to install it in a new sandbox with some verbosity: `mkdir /tmp/network; cd /tmp/network; cabal sandbox init; cabal install -j1 network`.

Comment: This also yielded similar results, when I run cabal install -j1 network -v I get makelike errors such as "No hmake found, No hugs found". Are these critical errors?

Comment: Can you post the output that command somewhere, eg a pastebin? Also, can you install other packages?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4bb309ef42c17323f2da7c132029e709. I can yes.

Comment: Does it work if you try to install an older version of `network`, e.g. `cabal install network-2.4.0.1` (in a clean sandbox again)?

Comment: No joy on other versions. Is it possible there is a collision between versions? I may have a default version of network installed.

Comment: you might also consider using [stack](http://haskellstack.org) instead of cabal...

Comment: could you please list your `ghc --version`, `cabal --version`a, the output of `ghc-pkg list`

Comment: @epsilonhalbe "The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3" "cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library" https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c1df7f21e6458e13269509d5a7f54c98

Comment: So it would seem according to the ghc-pkg list I have network 2.4.1.2, would this conflict with version happstack-server is dependent on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [`stack`](https://www.haskellstack.org/) it is fairly simply to install, also I would recommend using a newer version of GHC - this [`hvr-ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc) can help you (GHC 7.10.2 or 8.0.1 are recommended!)

Remove your old `./ghc` directory and reinstall your old tooling with stack

```
stack install ghcid
stack install ghc-mod
stack install happstack-server
```

**Note:** Do not forget to add `~/.local/bin` to your `$PATH` otherwise `ghc-mod` etc. will not be found.

If you do not want to use `stack` - you need to find the cabal-package that installed the network package in it's old version - install that one in a sandbox and then install happstack-server in another sandbox.

If I recall correctly - Cabal 1.16 does not support sandboxes.

Comment: So I am here, stacked up. I have been reading the docs. Is it possible for me to install happstack-server and import the module in an isolated .hs script anywhere or do I need to go through the stack project workflow (https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) just to import an external module?

Comment: You can use the script interpreter approach. I wrote up a blog post on that recently https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2016/08/bitrot-free-scripts